# Iterate over a potentially empty argument list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function which accepts an argument list `*args` each of which is a sequence. Inside the function each of the sequences is zipped together and iterated over row-wise with each row serving as arguments passed to an inner function.

The code looks like:

```
In [30]: def apply_args_at_kwargs(*args, **kwargs):
    ...:     for row in zip(*args):
    ...:         # call some function f(*row, **kwargs)
    ...:         print 'row = ', row
    ...:         

In [31]: apply_args_at_kwargs([1,2,3])
row =  (1,)
row =  (2,)
row =  (3,)

In [32]: apply_args_at_kwargs([1,2,3], ['a','b','c'])
row =  (1, 'a')
row =  (2, 'b')
row =  (3, 'c')
```

Which, as shown in #31 and #32 is operating as I would like.

The problem I have is that the inner function could potentially take no arguments but when I pass no arguments to the outer function or an empty container the code inside the for loop (which calls the inner function) is skipped entirely.

```
In [33]: apply_args_at_kwargs()  # loop skipped entirely

In [34]: apply_args_at_kwargs([])  # loop skipped entirely

In [35]: apply_args_at_kwargs([()])  # row should be `()` not `((),)`
row =  ((),)
```

If I specify a nested container `[()]` I get returned a nested container when what I'm after is `row = ()`.

Is there anyway to craft an input which does what I'm after? Or a better way of defining the function?

Note: I could just have an `if not args:  f(**kwargs)` block but the code calling the function isn't so simple and I'm trying to avoid duplicating it if possible

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
for row in zip(*args) if args else [()]:
```

Comment: Yep, that works nicely and is embarrassingly obvious! Thanks :)